# Installation of TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I am going to install TFS 2018 in a machine.
Do you think that I may face any kind of issues if Install it on Drive D instead of the default drive C?

It should be the same but I am just wondering if afterwards I may face any issue or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you **can specify a different installation drive during the install** should tell you that it will work fine.